# MongoDB Positional Operator $

Tags: mongodb

I got the following document

```
{
    _id : 91,
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "a" : "1",
            "b" : true
        }, 
        {
            "a" : "1",
            "b" : true
        }, 
        {
            "a" : "1",
            "b" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

And now I want to update each `myArray.b` element to `false` where `b` is `true`. So I am running following query:

```
db.MyDB.update({"arr.b" : true},{$set : {"arr.$.b":false}},false, true)
```

And I am getting just first array element updated not all subdocuments.

```
{
        _id : "91",
        "myArray" : [ 
            {
                "a" : "1",
                "b" : false
            }, 
            {
                "a" : "1",
                "b" : true
            }, 
            {
                "a" : "1",
                "b" : true
            }
        ]
    }
```

All sub-documents that match the arr.b:true criteria should be updated to `arr.b = false`.
According to this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StPhSsIkOh0#t=671) from MongoDB university this situation is possible.

I don't want to use JavaScript function.

What I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Try placing last two boolean parameters within an object and give the appropriate keys for upsert and multi. I don't think your query is registering the [multi keyword](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately updating all documents in array is not possible now - see MongoDB JIRA ticket [Use positional operator to update all items in an array](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243).

You can update each document manually:

```
db.MyDB.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { 
  doc.myArray.forEach(function(item) { 
     if (item.b === true) 
        item.b = false; 
  }); 

  db.MyDB.update({ "_id": doc._id }, { "$set": { "myArray": doc.myArray }});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey I know that, but watch what says in the video provided on updated question.

Comment: @NikolaMitev he says exactly same - 11:16 - "and the assumption here is that only one (item) will be matched. If multiple will be matched that will not achieve our goal"