# basic mongodb nested sets search, only want to retrieve single value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, nosql

I just started with document based datastores around 3-4 hours and I have a basic problem that I want to understand.

```
    {
      "_id": "5527e5ae06e55c02049bd114",
      "owner": "John Doe",
      "customers" : ["5527e3c806e55c01dad3a132", "5527e3c806e55c01dad3a133", "5527e3c806e55c01dad3a134"],
      "location" : [
        {
          "address": "Wall St",
          "location_id": "123123213",
          "vendor" : [
            {
              "name" : "hello 123",
              "price" : "3",
              "serial" : "000000009730978e"
            },
            {
              "name" : "hello abc",
              "price" : "3.5",
              "serial" : "0000000097308888"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "address" : "PCH 1",
          "location_id": "987987",
          "vendor" : [
            {
              "name" : "hello 456342",
              "price" : "4",
              "serial" : "000000009733452435"
            },
            {
              "name" : "hello sdfsdg",
              "price" : "4.5",
              "serial" : "0000000095243532453"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

So how can I find location.serial.price?

```
db.test.find_one( {"location.location_id" : "123123213" , "location.vendor.serial" : "000000009730978e"  }  )
```

would returns the entire object but I am just interested in location.serial.price where these conditions match.

Thanks a lot,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) use here, below query will satisfied your criteria

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$location"
},
{
    "$match": {
    "location.location_id": "123123213"
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$location.vendor"
},
{
    "$match": {
    "location.vendor.serial": "000000009730978e"
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
    "serial": "$location.vendor.serial",
    "price": "$location.vendor.price",
    "_id": 0
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: also agree with Philipp description `aggregation` affect performance also

Comment: Hi @yogesh: thanks a lot but I couldn't get it to run, here is my code [link](http://pastebin.ca/2970398) error message
File "yogesh.py", line 75, in <module>
    "_id": 0
TypeError: aggregate() takes exactly 2 arguments (6 given)

Comment: thank you very much! My mac kepped getting all sorts of errors, runs fine on my linux box. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use the [positional-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520055/mongodb-positional-operator) ($) to refer to array entries. But unfortunately this operator has a serious limitation: it does not work with nested arrays. So it does not help you in this case.

What you can do instead is use an aggregation pipeline which [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)s both arrays and then [match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)es the serial.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    // create a stream of location-documents
    { $unwind: "$location" },
    // filter the stream by location-id
    { $match: { "location.id" : "123123213" },
    // expand the remaining stream further to individual vendor-documents
    { $unwind: "$vendor" },
    // filter the stream by serial
    { $match: { "location.vendor.serial": "000000009730978e" } }
]);
```

Keep in mind that aggregation can become quite slow. It also has a limitation of 16MB per aggregation step. You can avoid that limit with the [`allowDiskUse:true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-external-sort) option, but that makes it even slower. So when you have lots of data and performance is a concern, you might want to reconsider your database schema.

Comment: thank you but I couldn't get it to run Code [link](http://pastebin.ca/2970400)
Error message [link](http://pastebin.ca/2970403)

Comment: @BenSchmidt Try it withouth the "$" in front of the field-names for the match stages.