# how to update the first object in the array of quarterFinals that matches some mongoDB condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the document below and I need to iterate through the quarterFinals array and update the first null address property I find to '123'

```
{
    "data": {
        "createTournament": {
            "_id": "613122d0c7befdeef3b0b571",
            "title": "Jogo de truco",
            "description": "",
            "location": "Batalha na rua",
            "type": "Battle",
            "players": [],
            "status": "PENDING",
            "size": 8,
            "entryFee": 1,
            "prizePool": 20,
            "currency": "USD",
            "startDate": "2021-09-01",
            "endDate": "2021-09-01",
            "rounds": {
                "quarterFinals": [{
                    "id": "9fb6f9ca-c06a-4972-b140-0f2425a90707",
                    "arena": "",
                    "firstParticipant": {
                        "address": null,
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    },
                    "secondParticipant": {
                        "address": null,
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the positional operator `$` in the update?  This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520055/mongodb-positional-operator

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Are you iterating in Mongoose or are you trying to iterate in the database server?

Comment: in the mongoose

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is

```
exports.updateData =  async (tournamentID,address)=>{
    return await db_collection.updateOne({id:tournamentId,rounds:{$elemMatch:{quarterfinals.address:null}}},{$push:{address:address});
};
```